# how to get error message in HP UFT and update in excel result

Tags: hp-uft

I would like to know can i able to get error message from HP run result viewer in script when UFT script got fail.

After script runs, I am uploading the results in excel with status and run time. but when it fails i am unable to find the reason for the failure.

Could you suggest the way to identify the failed result and update in excel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read ERR.Description/ DescribeResult and write that in excel.